# Splitting lapply for faster processing

Tags: r, performance, lapply

I am calling a function in R using `lapply`. This function is computationally demanding, especially when repeated many times (often >4000 times). Does R have a good way to split the job into separate smaller jobs and merge them together that would work faster than using my current code?

I found the split-apply-combine strategy from Hadley Wickham but I can't tell if this is suitable for this problem. The examples I found didn't seem to explicitly deal with splitting an lapply but the strategy seems appropriate. Would this be the best method to investigate or are there simpler approaches I should look into?

my current code:

```
output <- lapply(1:8000, simData, sampleSize )
```

Ideally I am looking for a way to slit it into smaller pieces that can be processed concurrently

eg

```
 output1 <-   lapply(1:1000, simData, sampleSize )
 output2 <-  lapply(1001:2000, simData, sampleSize )
 output3 <-   lapply(2001:3000, simData, sampleSize )
```

then combine the 3 outputs into one `output` object

I'd appreciate some suggestions on the most suitable type of approach for this in R.

Comment: OS is important. If you're using a non-windows OS, you can use `mclapply` from the `parallel` package.

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. Interesting I will look into that thanks